# Google Compute Engine Apache2 subdomain still directed a home instead of virtual host folder

Tags: apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I've been trying to create subdomains in my Google Cloud Console and then direct them to a folder in my /var/www directory.

I created a subdomain:

```
DNS Name: subdomain.example.com
Type: CNAME
TTL: 300
Data: example.com
```

I created a folder

> /var/www/subdomain

I created a file with message "Subdomain!"

> /var/www/subdomain/index.html

After, I duplicated my 000-default.conf

```
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.conf
```

I edited the new file code to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@subdomain.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.example.com/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I then did

```
sudo a2ensite subdomain.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Yet my subdomain is still directed at the document root `/var/www/html`

I noticed that when I do `systemctl reload apache2` I get error `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Did I miss a step or do I need to add something else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that http is configured but not https.

**Must add to default-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```